# MQTT source Spring XD

Tags: mqtt, spring-xd

Using the sink MQTT source module for Spring XD, I am getting wrong values on the payload. I have the stream subscribed to a certain topic and a normal client in eclipse also subscribed to the same topic. The payload is supposed to be an array of bytes. For the same message I am getting

xxxxx...0000073F, on Spring XD

xxxxx...000007F9, on eclipse Paho client

In reality, this value is supposed to be a counter, and the eclipse paho client behaves perfectly but Spring XD seems to behave a weird behavior when any of the hexadecimal digits reaches F. For same reason it gets stuck on the same number until the counter has increased enough to get rid of any F on the sequence.

My question would be, if there eny pre processing happening on the MQTT client provided on Spring XD that explains why I am getting different values on the payload. I am sure that the second is correct since it is myself who is sending the values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring XD uses [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mqtt.html) which uses the Paho client under the covers.

Unfortunately, it converts the payload to String (UTF-8 by default), which produces results like this with data that is not valid UTF-8.

The adapter can be configured to pass the payload as binary but, unfortunately, that option is not currently exposed in XD.

The work around is to create a sublass of `DefaultPahoMessageConverter`, override `mqttBytesToPayload` ...

```
protected Object mqttBytesToPayload(MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
    return mqttMessage.getPayload();
}
```

Put the converter in a jar in the module's `lib` directory, and update the mqtt.xml to pass an instance of the converter in the `converter` attribute.

I will open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2075)  to make binary a standard option of the module.

Comment: It works, but yes, it would be nice to have it as a default option. thanks for your help.